# Constrain plot points to below a certain line

Tags: plotting

I have a set of curves that take on large values when approaching 1. I'm trying to create a straight line with certain slope and then truncate the plot for any curve that goes above that line for any value of x. This is my current code:

```
lm := Sqrt[M^2 - 1]
C1 := 2/lm
C2 := ((1.4 + 1)*M^4 - 4 M^2 + 4)/(2*lm^4)      

pr1[o_, M_] := (C1*(o*Pi/180) + C2*(o*Pi/180)^2)*1.4*M^2/2 + 1;

Plot[Table[pr1[o, M], {o, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}}] // Release, {M, 1, 3}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't produce any points (i.e. produces an empty graph) in MMA v8.0.4. Should there be a semi-colon before `C1` and `C2`? If so, then a series of lines (not points) are produced. Also, there is nothing in the document center about `Release`?? (although I can see what it is doing here). How did you find out about it? Does anyone know if it is superseded?

Comment: @geordie, `Release[]` is a very, very old function. Nowadays, in this context, one would use `Evaluate[]`, which has the same purpose.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 With[{a = 1, b = 1}, 
   Plot[
     Join[Table[pr1[o, M], {o, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}}], 
          {a M + b}] // Evaluate,
     {M, 1, 3}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
     RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (y - b)/a >= x]]]
```

The option `RegionFunction` will exclude the region below the line $y=x+1$, for instance.

[image: some plots]

The command `Release` is obsolete; use `Evaluate` instead.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer constrains the curves in the wrong way. I believe the question asks for the parts of curves which are under the line.

Comment: This is just an example to get the feel of it if he wants below the curve he just reverses the $\ge$ to $\le$.